InaccessibleObjectException while doing assertThat isEqualTo in test
Getting this error while running a test to compare 2 XML objects -
org.assertj.core.util.introspection.IntrospectionError: 
Can't find any field or property with name 'orig_second'.
Error when introspecting properties was :
- No getter for property 'orig_second' in com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl 
Error when introspecting fields was :
- Unable to obtain the value of the field <'orig_second'> from <2023-06-06T16:58:29.053Z>

Caused by: org.assertj.core.util.introspection.IntrospectionError: Unable to obtain the value of the field <'orig_second'> from <2023-06-06T16:58:29.053Z>
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.FieldSupport.readSimpleField(FieldSupport.java:248)
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.FieldSupport.fieldValue(FieldSupport.java:202)
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.PropertyOrFieldSupport.getSimpleValue(PropertyOrFieldSupport.java:75)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient int com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.orig_second accessible: module java.xml does not "opens com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype" to unnamed module @36c88a32
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.FieldUtils.getField(FieldUtils.java:67)
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.FieldUtils.readField(FieldUtils.java:143)
    at org.assertj.core.util.introspection.FieldSupport.readSimpleField(FieldSupport.java:208)
    ... 52 more

Using Java 17
Was working few days back but suddenly getting this error, haven't changed any lib version or code.

The cause is what you should look further into Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient int com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.orig_second accessible: module java.xml does not "opens com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype" to unnamed module @36c88a32

@Naman isn't that the library's internal code erroring out

Can't comment without looking at the implementation that is throwing this exception. Most likely seems like the code is trying to use XMLGregorianCalendarImpl which should not be the case as stated here.

Try using withEqualsForType(Objects::equals,XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
ex:
assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison()
                                .withEqualsForType(Objects::equals,XMLGregorianCalendar.class)
                                .isEqualTo(expected);

